# python-selenium out put file duplicating

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on one automation project everything is working fine But while printing to page content to html file i am facing duplication issue could you please help me.

From the below code content of `logE2` and `logE1` should be different because they belong to different windows but i can see `logE1` is duplicated with the content of `logE2`

```
browser.switch_to_window(window_main)
title3 = browser.title
print title3

browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801800482').click()")
browser.switch_to_window(window_child1)
browser.implicitly_wait(300)

select233 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//td/nobr/span[text()="ALL_E2_incidents"]')
select233.click()
select = browser.find_elements_by_id("WIN_0_801600035")

browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801600035').click()")
browser.implicitly_wait(300)

select = browser.find_elements_by_id("WIN_0_801600020")

browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801600020').click()")
browser.implicitly_wait(300)

select = browser.find_elements_by_id("WIN_0_801600134")
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801600134').click()")

browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
contente2 = browser.page_source
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(contente2, "html5lib")
logE2 = open("c:\\E2incidents.html", "w")
print >>logE2, soup2

print "e2 finished"
title4 = browser.title
print title4
#############
browser.switch_to_window(window_child1)
browser.implicitly_wait(300)

select234 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//td/nobr/span[text()="ALL_E1_incidents"]')
select234.click()
select = browser.find_elements_by_id("WIN_0_801600035")
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801600035').click()")
browser.implicitly_wait(300)

select = browser.find_elements_by_id("WIN_0_801600020")
 browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801600020').click()")
browser.implicitly_wait(300)

select = browser.find_elements_by_id("WIN_0_801600134")
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('WIN_0_801600134').click()")
time.sleep(5)

browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
contente3 = browser.page_source
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(contente3, "html5lib")
logE3 = open("c:\\E1incidents.html", "w")
print >>logE3, soup3
print "e1 finished"
title5 = browser.title
print title5
```

Comment: In both cases you're executing `browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])` immediately before fetching the page source.  Wouldn't this result in the same source being used?

Comment: thanks for the update. Yes but added sleep before exicuting second one

Comment: experts, help me on this

Comment: Explain why you are calling `browser.switch_to_window()`.

Comment: john, " 'WIN_0_801600134').click()")"  will generate new window with result so i am using these parameters to switch in to the latest window

Comment: Does it generate a new window in both cases?  Or do both cases switch to the same window?

Comment: yes its generating different windows  with different content as per the search but the output html file will be same

Comment: Can you print the window handles to confirm that it's switching to two different windows?

Comment: Please see this i can see both windows are different with contents but handles are same. 
e2handle 10de92a6-b73c-4b74-a2ef-f7d56082d241,

e1handle 10de92a6-b73c-4b74-a2ef-f7d56082d241 any idea how to change this behavior

Comment: Perhaps one of the new windows is actually reusing a previous window instead of making a new window?

Comment: john, i am able to see all different windows and sometimes its working perfectly, i believe something related to page load :(